# remove Ethernet icon from toolbox

Tags: 22.04

I installed windows on VMware. Now there are two Ethernet icons in my toolbox. How can I remove this two icons?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those connections are used by VMWare.  The `vmnet1` is used for the `host-only` connection, and `vmnet8` is used for NAT (Network Address Translation) connections.

https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/What-is-the-VMware-Network-Adapter-VMnet8-and-VMware-Network/td-p/1123765

However, these are only needed if you use NAT or `host-only`.  I used Bridged so it gives it an IP based on my network instead of its own.  So these can be removed.

From a terminal run `vmware-netcfg` and you will get a screen like the following:

[image]

Then all you should have to do is select the `vmnet` you want to remove and click Remove Network.  Then click Save at the bottom and those connections should be gone.

Comment: My VMware software is closed, but I still see them. Is there a way to hide them?

Comment: Thanks from your Answer ❤️

Comment: @AliAshooriyoon Actually you are probably in luck if you use the bridged connection.  Let me fix my answer here.